# TFS 2013 git build authentication error with libgit2

Tags: git, tfs

I have private Git repository hosted on Linux and would like to use TFS 2013 for builds from it. Currently installed TFS 2013 Update 2. TFS build is always failed with error VS 30063 You are not authorized to access repository LibGit2SharpException in libgit2.

I've tried multiple options to configure users in git and tried to pass creadentials in URL, but it didn't helped.

Seems to be TFS 2013 is simply not working with private non-TFS-Git repositories. Does anybody has idea how to fix this error?

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  You're trying `http://user@pass:crucible.ert.com/...` ?  And that endpoints speaks HTTP Basic authentication?

Comment: Yes, I've tried URI http://user@pass:crucible.ert.com/ as workaround because it hasn't functioning with domain service account, which is used by TFS. In company is used NTLM but Git repo uses its own authentication independent from Active Directory. Unfortunately TFS has no possibility somehow to configure username/password for concrete Git repo

Comment: I've never tried this, and I'm not sure that it's supported.  I'll ask somebody from the build team.

Comment: Actually I would like to configure credentials somehow and prefer not to pass them in URL. But its workaround, because I don't see any possibility to configure it from UI either creating build definition or configuring TFS server

Comment: Sure; TFS build is aimed at building source in TFS, though, not an arbitrary repository.  You may be able to hook this up, though; I will let you know what I discover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched a little bit and also contacted Microsoft Support and scenario described in question is not supported by current version of Visual Studio and TFS (both 2013 Update 2).

> The scenario to build from non-TFS Git repositories is not supported
>   at this time. If there’s any other area that I can help you with
>   please let me know.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh850445.aspx

[image]